# attach css class to multiple divs by click

Tags: javascript, css, class, copy, transformation

I have a menu that should trigger CSS3 transformations on div-containers that contain content.
By a click on a menu link(no reload) the class of a span next to it should be read out and copied on the divs.

So for example by a click on "company" the class "show-right" of the span next to the link in the menu should be applied on all 3 divs with the id="cube" and the class "show-front" will be overwritten.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L98yr7b0/7/

The problem I have is that my function only applies the first class it finds of all spans and ends. How can I get every class applied to the cube divs?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="menu">
<ul>
    <li class="current"><span class="show-front"></span><a class="home menu-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><span class="show-right"></span><a class="company menu-link" href="#unternehmen">Company</a></li>
    <li><span class="show-left"></span><a class="service menu-link" href="#service">Service</a></li>
    <li><span class="show-back"></span><a class="services menu-link" href="#services">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
  <section class="cube-wrapper">
    <div id="cube" class="show-front">
      <figure class="front">1</figure>
      <figure class="back">2</figure>
      <figure class="right">3</figure>
      <figure class="left">4</figure>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="cube-wrapper">
    <div id="cube" class="show-front">
      <figure class="front">1</figure>
      <figure class="back">2</figure>
      <figure class="right">3</figure>
      <figure class="left">4</figure>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="cube-wrapper">
    <div id="cube" class="show-front">
      <figure class="front">1</figure>
      <figure class="back">2</figure>
      <figure class="right">3</figure>
      <figure class="left">4</figure>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**JS**

```
  $('.menu-link').bind('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var linksource = $('.menu ul li').children('span');
      $('.cube-wrapper').children().attr('class', (linksource.attr('class')));


      console.log($('.menu ul li').children('span'));
      console.log($('.menu ul li').children().attr('class'));
  });
```

Comment: multiple ids!!! use `class` instead

Comment: I use the ID's to prevent to be overwritten by my function. By copying the class from the span the cube class would be overwritten and that's not what I want. Therefore I use the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7t6zbkco/1/)**

```
$(".menu li a").click(function(){
    var clazz = $(this).data("class");
    $(".section-wrapper .cube").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("cube").addClass(clazz);
    });
});
```

I removed duplicate `id`s and added *cube* as a class
and instead of `span`s(which were lying there for no reason), I've used `data` attribute for `class` names.

**Refer**

http://api.jquery.com/each/

http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Ah, data attributes are more comfortable - great idea! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this , since ".cube-wrapper" will return more than 1 elements, you should use .each() to loop though it

```
$('.cube-wrapper').each(function()
{
    $(this).children().attr('class', (linksource.attr('class')));
});
```

And ID must be unique in whole html file, therefore you should not use id="cube" more than once.